# 406 Not Acceptable error while rendering a json view in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, view

My controller:

```
def index
    @feed_items = get_network_feed(current_user)
    respond_to do |f|
      f.json { render :json => @feed_items, :content_type => "application/json" }
    end
end
```

My view: #index.json.erb

```
{
Items: <%= @feed_items.to_json.html_safe %>
}
```

I get a 406 Not acceptable error. Can anyone tell me what I missed here?

Thanks,
pR

Comment: No, I mean with what technology. Javascript, RSpec, Wget, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your controller, I think it will solve your problem!

```
def index
    @feed_items = get_network_feed(current_user)        
    render :json => @feed_items, :content_type => "application/json"
end
```